# How to make 'attr_reader' or 'attr_writer' for all class variables at one time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and, since I have a declared a class with a lot of variables, I would declare all 'attr_reader' or 'attr_writer' for those class variables *at one time*.

I tryed

```
class Persone
  attr_reader :all

  def initialize(name, surname, ...)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    ... # A lot of variables!
  end
end
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: I assume `Persone` inherits from ActiveRecord? Since you're using Rails it would seem that it would but your excerpt doesn't reflect that.

Comment: No, in this case that don't inherits from ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Persone
  INSTANCE_VARS = [:name,:surname]
  attr_reader *INSTANCE_VARS

  def initialize(*params)
    params.each_with_index do |param,index|
      instance_variable_set("@"+INSTANCE_VARS[index].to_s,param)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I thing you should use:

```
attr_accesor :name, :surname, ...

def initialize(name, surname, ...)
  @name = name
  @surname = surname
  ...
end
```

This way you get a setter and a getter in only one step, but you still have to enum all that variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Struct.html) class:

```
Persone = Struct.new :name, :surname, :address

p = Persone.new 'John', 'Smith', '12 Street 345'
puts p.address
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be late, but late is better than never:

```
class Persone    
  def initialize(name, surname, ...)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    ... # A lot of variables!

    instance_variables.each do |var|
        eval "def #{var.to_s.sub('@', '')}; #{i}; end"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Persone

  VARS = [:name, :surname, ...]

  VARS.each{|var|
    attr_reader var
  }

  def initialize(params)
    params.each_pair{|key,value|
       self.instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, value
    }
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

the instance_variable block had a typo in Chris Wouters example...

```
instance_variables.each do |var|
    eval "def #{var.to_s.sub('@', '')}\n #{var}; end"
  end
```